# Writting a Django Query for Nested MySQL or SQL queries

Tags: mysql, django

I have a query[1] in MySQL which im using to derive an answer for the question (Movies in which acted has acted) .I am getting the correct rowset in MySQL.

I now want to know how can I convert query[1] into a Django query :: the query is as follow::

```
SELECT movie_name 
  FROM movies_movie 
 WHERE movie_id 
    IN ( SELECT movie_id 
           FROM movies_crew 
          WHERE Crew_name_id 
             IN ( SELECT crew_id 
                    FROM movies_crewname 
                   WHERE name 
                    LIKE %shaun%));
```

NOTE::

- The `movie_id` is the PK of `movies` table
- `movies_crew` contains `crew_name_id` (referenced from `movies_crewname`) and `movie_id` (referenced from `movies`)
- `movies_crewname` contains `crew_id` as PK

Can someone please show me the right way to write Django query?

Answer (score 2):

```
Movie.objects.filter(crew__crewname__name__icontains="shaun")
```